# .NET local restrictions for POST reception

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I am attempting to send some XMl via `cUrl` from a PHP form on my Apache localhost, to a `.ashx` listener class with `ProcessRequest()` that runs on my .NET localhost.

I have Apache and .NET running on separate ports and they work fine, the issue is that the `cURL` returns a 500 Internal server error.

My `cURL` works fine for Requestb.in and had no issues, however upon sending to my local .NET development server I get the error `No parameterless constructor defined for this object`. I have no idea why this is happening, at first I thought perhaps an authorization issue but have set the correct authorization for the page to no avail (code below).

```
  <location path="AccountHandler.ashx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Here is my `cURL` code:

```
function DoPostRequest($url, $xml){

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                           'Authorization:  BASIC ' . base64_encode("test:test"),
                                           'Content-type: application/xml', 
                                           'Content-length: ' . strlen($xml),
                                           'User-Agent: Googlebot/2.1',
                                         ));
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output; 
}
```

Is there some kind of local .NET prevention from receiving POST on localhost? That would seem very odd to me but looking back I do remember not being able to receive push notifications from a third party API on my local environment in the past.

Is this the issue or is there some configuration issue I am overlooking?

Comment: _"Is there some kind of local .NET prevention from receiving POST on localhost? [...] is there some configuration issue I am overlooking?"_ - No, there is an error with your .NET code: _"No parameterless constructor defined for this object"_. Attach a debugger to your service and see what happens when you POST your request, enable tracing, implement logging, and so on. It seems like one of your data contracts doesn't have a parameterless constructor defined.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I have put breakpoints in but they never reach the page at all, I'll do as you suggest and report back, I'm relatively new to .NET so I'll do my best, thanks!